# Python Inserting Unwanted Characters

Tags: python, html, regex, html-table, import-from-csv

I'm trying to use Python to generate a collection of HTML tables with values pulled from a CSV. The script is working fine, however it's adding in odd "¬†" characters wherever a value is pulled in.

This is the code I used to grab the CSV data:

```
import csv
import fileinput
import re

out=open("audiencestats.csv","rU")
data=csv.reader(out)
values =[row for row in data]
metrics = values.pop(0) 
out.close()
```

This creates a function to make the html tables:

```
def maketable(leftmetric, rightmetric, leftvalue, rightvalue):
  template = '''
  <table width="99%%" border="1"> 
   <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">
    <h3>%s</h3>
    </td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">
    <h3>%s</h3>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle"> %s</td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle"> %s</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  '''
  file.write(template % (leftmetric, rightmetric, leftvalue, rightvalue))
```

Then this writes the tables to text files:

```
for i in values:
  filename = "%s.txt" % i[0]
  file = open(filename , 'w')
  file.write(header)
  maketable(metrics[1],metrics[2],i[1],i[2])
  maketable(metrics[3],metrics[4],i[3],i[4])
  maketable(metrics[5],metrics[6],i[5],i[6])
  maketable(metrics[7],metrics[8],i[7],i[8])
  maketable(metrics[9],metrics[10],i[9],i[10])
  maketable(metrics[11],metrics[12],i[11],i[12])
  file.write(header2)
  print makesocial(i[13],i[14],i[15])
  file.close()
```

I tried adding in the below re.sub to the for loop, but the crosses remain.

```
for line in fileinput.input(inplace=1):
    line = re.sub('¬†','', line.rstrip())
    print(line)
```

Am I missing something? Has my computer turned religious?

Example of the output copied below as well:

```
<h1>Audience</h1>
  <table width="99%" border="1"> 
   <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">
    <h3>UVs (000)</h3>
    </td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">
    <h3>PVs (000)</h3>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">¬†580.705</td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">¬†1003</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Is it a Unicode currency symbol of some sort? What's in the CSV file? What are the binary values of the two characters?

Comment: This smells like an encoding problem. What encoding is the CSV file in? Can you upload (a small sample of) it somewhere, or just open it as a binary file and `print(' '.join(hex(ord(c)) for c in f.readline()))` or similar?

Comment: Also, why would you try to use `re.sub` to substitute out a fixed substring? Just use `str.replace` for that.

Comment: Also, you're presumably using Python 2.x. If so, it's a very, very bad idea to put non-ASCII characters into a non-Unicode literal like `'¬†'`, and an even worse idea to put non-ASCII characters into a source file without an [encoding declaration](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/), and an even worse idea to put them into a source file without knowing (and mentioning in your question) what encoding your text editor uses.

Comment: The csv is one row of headers and then 30 or so rows of data, it looks like this:  
`name,metric1,metric2,metric3`  
`john,a,b,c,d`  
`bill,e,f,g,h`  
`harry,i,j,k,l`

Comment: @PeterAlfvin According to binaryhexconverter.com the codes are 10101100 for "¬" and 10001000 "†". I'm not sure if it's currency.

Comment: @abarnert I tried str.replace but to no avail, but will use it in the future from now on. The encoding is all utf-8, I didn't include it on the example but there is `# coding=utf-8` on top of the script

Comment: @nslamberth: Those are the codes in cp1252, and various other Microsoft/IBM extended-Latin-1 codepages, but not in UTF-8 (or real Latin-1, or anything else). So clearly, there is more encoding confusion than you think. Are you sure the source file is actually saved as UTF-8, matching the coding declaration? Are you sure the CSV file is in UTF-8? And again, if you don't know how to tell for sure, upload them (as a binary upload, not text, and definitely not copy-paste… put them in a .zip if you don't know how to make sure of that) somewhere and someone else can check them for you.

Comment: @nslamberth: Also, exactly how are you viewing the output file? If you create files in UTF-8, then open them in a text editor or spreadsheet that expects them to be cp1252, they won't look right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your data—it's pure ASCII. The problem is in your source code.

Clicking the Edit button to copy your actual source, rather than your formatted source, it's got non-breaking space (U+00A0) characters in the middle of the `template` string literal.

Assuming your editor and the browser you copied from and pasted to are doing things right, that means that your actual UTF-8 source has `'\xc2\xa0'` sequences.

Since you're putting non-ASCII characters into a `str`/`bytes` literal (which, as I explained in the other answer, is *always* a bad idea), this means your strings end up with `'\xc2\xa0'` sequences.

Somewhere between there and your screen, there's an additional coding problem, and this is getting garbled into `'\xc2\xac\xe2\x80\xa0'` sequences—which, when interpreted as UTF-8, show up as `u'¬†'`.

We could try to track down where that additional problem is coming from, but it doesn't matter too much.

The immediate fix is to replace all the non-breaking spaces in your source with plain ASCII spaces.

Going beyond that, you need to figure out what you were using that generated these non-breaking spaces. Often, this is a sign of editing source code in word processors rather than text editors; if so, stop doing that.

If you don't actually have any intentionally-non-ASCII source code, using `# coding=ascii` instead of `# coding=utf-8` at the top of your file is a great way to catch bugs like this. (You can still process UTF-8 values; all the coding declaration says is that the source code itself is in UTF-8.)

Comment: Excellent! That got it.

If you look in the source code above in the maketable function there is an extra space on the line that reads `<td align="center" valign="middle"> %s</td>`

The space before `%s` was getting converted to the cross.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You still haven't answered the questions I asked to clarify this, so I'm going to take a guess here.

First, the reason your `re.sub` doesn't work is that your pattern is a UTF-8 `¬†` (`'\xc2\xac\xe2\x80\xa0'`), but you're trying to match a cp1252 `¬†` (`'\xac\x86'`). Obviously, those don't match.

Second, the reason you're getting that garbage in the first place is that your CSV file is being processed by something that's not using UTF-8, even though you think it is. Maybe it's your spreadsheet program, or a text editor, or a command-line tool.

Most likely, you've just mixed up one 8-bit encoding with another at some step on the chain—written out some text as cp1252, then tried to edit it as UTF-8, or vice-versa.

But that `†` is pretty interesting. That's U+2020. If you have some UTF-16-LE text, and edit it as UTF-8 (or ASCII or cp1252), and try to add in a pair of spaces, you're actually adding in one U+2020. Normally, you'd think it would be hard to mix up UTF-16 and UTF-8. But clearly you're just eyeballing the text instead of actually looking at the bytes, and if all of your data fits within Latin-1, UTF-16 will look perfectly fine to your eyeball—sure, there's an invisible NUL character after each real character, but you can't see invisible things.

Anyway, it doesn't matter what the exact details are. The only way to fix this is to look at the actual bytes in the file generated at each step on the chain, find out where you're doing it wrong, and fix it appropriately. If you don't know how to do any part of that, you need to give other people enough information to do it for you.

However, if you just want a quick workaround: Take the file that you're feeding into your Python script, and view it in a hex editor. Find the two garbage characters, and record what bytes they are. If they're, say, `ac 86`, just change your code to do a `s = s.replace('\xac\x86', '')`.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth analysis, very enlightening.

I've opened up the CSV in a hex editor (Hex Fiend) but am not seeing the garbage characters. All of the data points are separated by "2C" which is coming out as a comma, but no trace of ¬†.

I tried replacing '\xac\x86' and '\xc2\xac\xe2\x80\xa0' as well but the characters still show up.

Here is a few lines of the hex codes I got by opening the csv as a binary and running print(' '.join(hex(ord(c)) for c in f.readline())) as you suggested. I've posted them in the next comment.

Comment: `0x32 0x25 0x2c 0x33 0x30 0x2e 0x37 0x36 0x33 0x2c 0x38 0x33 0x2e 0x35 0x30 0x38 0x2c 0x33 0x31 0x35 0x2e 0x34 0x36 0x39 0x2c 0x38 0x32 0x25 0x2c 0x2c 0x2c 0x2c 0x2c 0x35 0x36 0x2c 0x35 0x37 0x38 0x39 0x2c 0x37 0x37 0x38 0x30 0xd 0x50 0x6f 0x74 0x68 0x6f 0x6c 0x65 0x73 0x20 0x49 0x6e 0x20 0x4d 0x79 0x20 0x42 0x6c 0x6f 0x67 0x2c`

Comment: There are no weird characters that far into the file (it ends with `Potholes In My Blog,`, if that helps). In particular, this is all still part of the first row, which is used for the `metrics` rather than the `i`, and the weird characters seem to be showing up in the `i` values, so… Can you post the whole file somewhere, or a hexdump of a larger initial fragment than this?

Comment: Sure, try this link: http://cl.ly/text/280a1U1N1D44

It's the whole hex dump saved to a .txt, unless there's a better way to save just hex values without worrying about encoding.

Comment: That's good enough; you can always unhexlify it in a one-liner at the Python interactive interpreter (for this format, `[int(x, 16) for x in s.split()]` works). Anyway, there are no non-ASCII (>0x7f) characters anywhere, so… I don't know where the problem is. I'll try running your code against it to see what happens when I get a chance.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
line = re.sub(r'(?u)¬†','', line.rstrip())
```

Then the regex treat your string as unicode.

Comment: All the `re.UNICODE`/`?u` flag does is change the way the meaning of the built-in character classes. See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.UNICODE). Also, it's generally a bad idea to use `?u` with non-Unicode pattern strings.